# Загрузка фото на сайт и получение результата selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Мне срочно нужна помощь, буду очень-очень благодарен! Нужно отправить фотографию на сервис **toonify.photos** и придать настройки фотографии и ждать результата, и скачать этот результат (изменённая фотография). Я уже немного изучил их документацию и был даже код построенный на requests, который я собирался использовать с API ключом, но тут мне сказали что такая версия не годится и нужна версия без этого, то есть через selenium, а с ним я вообще не знаком, но надо сделать за 1 день... Очень нуждаюсь в помощи! Заранее огромное спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы успели уже посмотреть, сделать за столь короткое время? самостоятельно?

Comment: Это только вчера мне сказали, что надо с селениумом, а до этого я изучал как делать с помощью запросов через API ключ